# Can't find option to activate Paginated Reports in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

According to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-premium-manage), it's now possible to preview a new function in Power BI Premium: Paginated Reports (Reporting Services / rdl files).

When administrating my capacity settings, I don't see the option to enable "Paginated Reports (Preview)". Is this available in North Europe?
We only see the option to enable "Dataflows".
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. According to [Christopher Finlan](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/public-preview-of-paginated-reports-in-power-bi-premium-now-available/): "it's still getting rolled out to all the regions worldwide. Give it another day or two."

Comment: I now see the option to enable "Paginated Reports (Preview)"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports-report-builder-power-bi